# Branching statement: better a break or a return inside a for/while cycle?

Tags: java, branch, cycle

Obviously with return only in the case that the method can immediately exit

```
for (...) {
   return;
}
```

or

```
for () {
   break;
}
```

Which is better?

Comment: *related* : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement

Comment: break and return have different behaviour, so there isn't really an answer to asking which is "better"

Answer (score 3):

The two examples you gave aren't exactly equivalent so it's a little difficult to say which is better style. Here are two approaches that are slightly more similar in what they do:

```
for (Foo foo: foos) {

    // ...

    if (ok) { return foo; }
}
return null;
```

Versus:

```
Foo result = null;

for (Foo foo: foos) {

    // ...

    if (ok) {
        result = foo;
        break;
    }
} 

return result;
```

In this case I'd recommend the first because it's much simpler. It is unlikely that there is a significant performance difference. Some people prefer the second because they only want a single return in each function, but I don't think it is always a good idea to stick to that rule. Sometimes multiple return statements makes things much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest the break approach.  It looks like more code but is easier to understand.  Also, making changes later is easier.  You can go for labeled loops for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

> Obviously with `return` only in the case that the method can immediately exit

You've answered your own question. These two have different semantics and aren't really interchangeable, and the `return` variant is applicable only to more specific scenarios...

...thus *precisely in those specific scenarios* you should use the `return` variant. The intention is immediately obvious and thus it makes for better readability. If you use a `break` when `return` suffices, then the reader must spend more time to figure out what happens after the `break`. When nothing significant happens, a `return` would've quickly conveyed this much more clearly.